# Why do I not have access to a parent-scope variable in one "then" block, but I do have access in a subsequent block?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm contributing to an open-source Ember app, and I'm attempting to chain several promises together.  The intent of the code below is to set a user into the `current_user` document of the PouchDB store, and then set their i18n preferences into the `preferences` store.  Here's the code:

```
setCurrentUser(userName) {                                 // block 0
  let config = this.get('configDB');
  let sessionData = this.get('sessionData');
  if (!userName && sessionData.authenticated) {
    userName = sessionData.authenticated.name;
  }
  config.get('current_user').then((doc) => {               // block 1
    doc.value = userName;
    config.put(doc);
    return userName;
  }).then((user) => {                                      // block 2
    let configDB = this.get('configDB');
    let preferences = configDB.get('preferences');
    let promises = { user, preferences };
    return RSVP.hash(promises);
  }).then((promises) => {                                 //  block 3
    let { preferences } = promises;
    let userName = promises.user.name || 'default';
    this.set('i18n.locale', preferences[userName].i18n);
  }).catch((err) => {                                      // block 4
    console.log(err);
    config.put({_id: 'current_user', value: userName});
  });
}
```

As you can see, the `userName` variable is passed in as a parameter to the `setCurrentUser` method.  Because of this, I would expect to have access to this parameter inside each of the blocks of code inside each `then` block.

However that's not the case.  I do have access to it in blocks 0, 1, 3, and even in the scope of `catch` in block 4.  But for some reason, I don't have access to it in block 2.  The above code, specifically the passing of the RSVP object with both the preferences doc and the user object, represents a hacky workaround to make my code work.  However, I'd prefer to do something like this:

```
setCurrentUser(userName) {                                 // block 0
  let config = this.get('configDB');
  let sessionData = this.get('sessionData');
  if (!userName && sessionData.authenticated) {
    userName = sessionData.authenticated.name;
  }
  config.get('current_user').then((doc) => {               // block 1
    doc.value = userName;
    config.put(doc);
    return userName;
  }).then((user) => {                                      // block 2
    let configDB = this.get('configDB');
    let preferences = configDB.get('preferences');
    return preferences[userName].i18n || preferences['default'].i18n;
  }).then((i18nPreference) => {                            // block 3
    this.set('i18n.locale', i18nPreference);
  }).catch((err) => {                                      // block 4
    console.log(err);
    config.put({_id: 'current_user', value: userName});
  });
}
```

In fact, I've tried the above, but I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: userName is not defined` inside block 2 and therefore get routed to the `catch` block.

My question is, what is the difference between blocks 0/1/3/4 and block 2, which would allow the first blocks to access `userName` but would prevent block 2 from doing so?

Comment: I got doubt, You are returning `userName` , can we put `}).then((user) => {` from there ? will this work ?

Comment: @kumkanillam I don't understand your meaning.  Do you mean delete the line `return userName;` and simply move the `}).then((user) => {` up by 1 line?  Then what would we be passing to the next `then` block?

Comment: ignore my comments, That's my misunderstanding of promise. for me your code looks good. May be try commenting this line `doc.value = userName;
    config.put(doc);`

Comment: You're going to need to reduce your code to a reproducible example. As it is, you can absolutely access that variable in all of the blocks: https://jsfiddle.net/Laayk2g1/

Comment: Is it possible `setCurrentUser` is being called without a `userName` and that block is just the first place you error out?

Comment: @max if that were the case, wouldn't the expected behavior in the devtools console be for userName to equal `undefined` (rather than throwing the `ReferenceError` message)?

Comment: @RichieThomas unsure--I would put a `debugger;` before the last reference to userName, and see what it's value is, as well as the result of `preferences[userName]`.

Comment: @max just tried your suggestion.  I observed that 'userName' is `undefined` in certain cases, for instance when I log out and am returned to the login route.  In this case I get `nil` for `preferences[userName]` as expected (and an error in the console due to calling `i18n` on `undefined`, but that's actually a different problem that I'll solve next).  When I expect to have a value for `userName` (for instance, after I'm logged in), its value is an object in blocks 0, 1, 3, and 4, but in block 2 I get the `ReferenceError` when I type `userName` in the console.

Comment: Hm. In the first example, I see you have a second `let userName` declaration, I wonder if you still are redefining it anywhere such that at that scope, it is not defined--checking transpiled js is probably the way to go there... Barring that, it looks like `user === userName` in block 2, could you just rename `user` to `userName` in the function parameters?

Comment: Update: just in the last hour, I decided to extract the code to a separate service and re-write the function from scratch, and the following code ended up working: https://pastebin.com/Dw53eiNC  I still don't know why it works now and didn't earlier, but I guess that's one of many coding mysteries I must learn to live with. :-)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, userName doesn't have a capital N in your code (so it's a different variable):

```
}).then((user) => {
   let configDB = this.get('configDB');
   let preferences = configDB.get('preferences');
   return preferences[username] || preferences['default'];
```

You say this code is for illustrative purposes only. It would be good to know what is the actual code that returns the error message to have a better idea.

Comment: What I meant by `illustrative purposes` was that the code you were referencing was essentially pseudo-code, however I've updated the example code with a specific example I've tried which failed.  The error I get inside block 2 returns the error I mentioned in my question (i.e. `Uncaught ReferenceError: userName is not defined`).